# Ferrite antenna impedance matching

Tags: operational-amplifier, antenna, impedance, impedance-matching, magnetics

I want to use a tuned ferrite antenna with my RTL-SDR. From what I understand at the point of resonance, only the real (resistive) impedance remains. This should be a few ohms for the resistance of the wire, capacitor and ferrite losses.

The input pins of the RTL-SDR are about 3300 ohms, how do I go about matching these two ?

I was thinking of a negative feedback amplifier, I've seen some examples of this online but it is generally used for broadband matching when there is no capacitor. Can this also be used for a tuned antenna ?

Here is an example of an amplifier used in this way, the rest of the circuit is irrelevant. I won't post a 1000 pictures but a google of "broadband magnetic antenna schematic" shows this is a recurring method.

[image]

Comment: What is the resonance frequency you want to operate?

Comment: I need to operate at 100KHz

Comment: And why do you want to impedance match? What is it that needs to be matched (your opinion required here)? Also take note that the normal payment for getting good answers is an upvote (even if you don't like what they say because it exposes your lack of knowledge (being a relative thing)) followed by formal answer acceptance for the best answer (in your opinion) to each question that has an answer you clearly found useful.

Comment: From what I understand its in the interest of maximum power transfer, if both impedance are match you effectively have less noise. I am aware that impedance matching for receiving antennas isn't as crucial as transmitting ones, but I think this mismatch is too big in my case.